# Create a watermark in a separate track with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

I have a PNG (alpha) file and a video file. I want to create a video in which the first track is the image and the second track is the video (PNG over video). The problem is that the PNG doesn't preserves transparency.

I need create a watermark (PNG) in a separate track with ffmpeg over video track.

```
ffmpeg -i base.mov -i logo.png -map 0 -map 1 output.mov
```

I needed the watermark is on a track (stream) separately in order to enable or disable it with quicktime pro.

Thanks.